# Given the matrix product $AB$ how can I determine the product $BA$

Tags: matrices

I have matrices $A\ (4×2)$ and $B\ (2×4)$
$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}
\pi&0&-\pi&0\\
0&\pi&0&-\pi\\
-\pi&0&\pi&0\\
0&-\pi&0&\pi\end{bmatrix}$$
I need to find $BA$

---

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d\\
e&f\\
g&h\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
i&j&k&l\\
m&n&o&p\end{bmatrix}$$

Then
$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}
ai+bm&aj+bn&ak+bo&al+bp\\
ci+dm&cj+dn&ck+do&cl+dp\\
ei+fm&ej+fn&ek+fo&el+fp\\
gi+hm&gj+hn&gk+ho&gl+hp\end{bmatrix}$$

$$BA=\begin{bmatrix}
ai+cj+ek+gl&bi+dj+fk+hl\\
am+cn+eo+gp&bm+dn+fo+hp\end{bmatrix}$$

If I summarize all elements in AB, I'll get (a+c+e+g)(i+j+k+l)+(b+d+f+h)(m+n+o+p)=0
Also I know, that in BA element(1.1)+element(2.2)=4*pi
So, knowing all that, I need find four elements in BA.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please provide details on what you tried to do to solve this problem and where you get stuck. As it is currently written, your question looks like a homeworks problem.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Not that there is anything wrong with homework problems as such, but we do encourage (and occationally expect) people to make some effort on their own before posting here.

Comment: The most straightforward way is to multiply two matrices and compare the entries of the product with the given expression. But I think there should be a easier way.

Comment: Maybe finding eigenvalues can lead to a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try. Write $A =  \begin{pmatrix}A_1 \\ A_2\end{pmatrix}$, $B = \begin{pmatrix}B_1 & B_2\end{pmatrix}$, where $A_i$, $B_j$ is $2\times 2$ matrix.

We have $AB = \begin{pmatrix}A_1B_1 & A_1B_2 \\ A_2B_1 & A_2B_2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\pi I_2 &-\pi I_2\\-\pi I_2 & \pi I_2\end{pmatrix}$.

So, you have $A_1B_1 = \pi I_2$, $A_1B_2=-\pi I_2$, $A_2B_1 = \pi I_2$, $A_2B_2 = \pi I_2$. Then, you have $B_1A_1 = B_2A_2 = \pi I_2 =$

Now, you have $BA =B_1A_1 + B_2A_2 = 2\pi I_2.$